# illegal use of LONG datatype 00997. 00000 - "illegal use of LONG datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, informix

If I have two tables with the same structure one in `informix` and the other in `oracle` db.and i want to migrate the photos from `informix` to `oracle` so i use the oracle gateway to achieve this migration but it failed and i get the following error :

---

> SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
>   00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"

---

My Query :

```
INSERT INTO EMPPHOTO (EMP_NUM,EMP_PIC,THUMB)
SELECT "emp_num","emp_pic","thumb" FROM "empmaster1pics"@GMR;
```

Where `EMPPHOTO` (oracle table ) and `EMP_PIC --->BLOB`

and

`empmaster1pics` (informix table) and `emp_pic --->Byte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing an implicit [conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/gateways.112/e12066/apa.htm) from the Informix data type to the Oracle one. But [you can't use `to_lob()` with a remote table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_long_lob.htm#ADLOB45622), which is the explicit equivalent.

You should be able to achieve this with a PL/SQL cursor, separating the query and the insert:

```
begin
  for rec in (
    select "emp_num", "emp_pic", "thumb"
    from "empmaster1pics"@GMR
  )
  loop
    insert into empphoto (emp_num, emp_pic, thumb)
    values (rec."emp_num", rec."emp_pic", rec."thumb");
  end loop;
end;
/
```

I don't have an Informix database to verify, but it works with a link to an Oracle database and a table with a `long raw` column, which is the closest equivalent to your `byte` column and which gets the same ORA-00997 with your original code. (Except you can only have one `long raw` column in a table, so I've only been able to test with `emp_pic` or `thumb`, not both).

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare - I'd left a null placeholder in what I posted, from testing with the single-long Oracle link; hopefully you spotted that and you haven't inserted a load of null values in your emp_pic column....

Comment: No i use "emp_pic" and every thing goes okay, really thanks a lot :D